# FileNotFoundException while appending message to a MaildirFolder

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use JavaMaildir (http://sourceforge.net/projects/javamaildir/) to store locally some emails retrieved online. Unfortunately, I'm unable to understand what this FileNotFoundException means. Here is an example code that reproduces the problem:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.URLName;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirFolder;
import net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirStore;


public class MaildirStoreTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        String mdirpath = "/tmp/TestMaildir";

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("mail.store.maildir.autocreate", "true");

        Session s = Session.getDefaultInstance(p);
        s.setDebug(true);

        MaildirStore st = (MaildirStore)s.getStore(new URLName("maildir:"+mdirpath));

        MaildirFolder fd = (MaildirFolder) st.getDefaultFolder();

        fd.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(s);
        m.setText("Hello World!");

        fd.appendMessages(new Message[]{m});

        st.close();
    }

}
```

The last but one code line throws a `FileNotFoundException`. Here is the error log:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,maildir,net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirStore,Priocom Corp.]
unrecoverable io error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/TestMaildir/./tmp/1388665301.33536.francesco-laptop (No such file or directory)
javax.mail.MessagingException: unrecoverable io error;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/TestMaildir/./tmp/1388665301.33536.francesco-laptop (No such file or directory)
    at net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirFolder.appendMessages(MaildirFolder.java:469)
    at MaildirStoreTest.main(MaildirStoreTest.java:34)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/TestMaildir/./tmp/1388665301.33536.francesco-laptop (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirFolder.getTmpFileOutputStream(MaildirFolder.java:401)
    at net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirFolder.appendMessages(MaildirFolder.java:458)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: cant append message;
  nested exception is:
    javax.mail.MessagingException: unrecoverable io error;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/TestMaildir/./tmp/1388665301.33536.francesco-laptop (No such file or directory)
    at net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirFolder.appendMessages(MaildirFolder.java:527)
    at MaildirStoreTest.main(MaildirStoreTest.java:34)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: unrecoverable io error;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/TestMaildir/./tmp/1388665301.33536.francesco-laptop (No such file or directory)
    at net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirFolder.appendMessages(MaildirFolder.java:469)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/TestMaildir/./tmp/1388665301.33536.francesco-laptop (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirFolder.getTmpFileOutputStream(MaildirFolder.java:401)
    at net.ukrpost.storage.maildir.MaildirFolder.appendMessages(MaildirFolder.java:458)
    ... 1 more
```

The provider seems to be loaded correctly, but I don't really get why it's looking for that file... shouldn't it create that file instead??

The `/tmp/TestMaildir` folder exists and is writable by my user. I'm on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about JavaMaildir, and this may have nothing to do with the error you're getting, but normally Store.getDefaultFolder does not return a folder that you can store messages in.  It returns a folder that you can think of as the "root" folder in the folder naming hierarchy.  You'll want to create a folder underneath that folder in which to store messages.

The "default" folder is **not**, for example, your "Inbox", where messages are delivered by default.

Comment: You were right. I would only add that the `INBOX` folder is not created by default. The root folder is empty and you have to create the `INBOX` folder with type `Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES`. Thank you very much.